# Deal with CacheOutput from another website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

I have an Action in a Controller that uses the OutputCache attribute

```
public class PostsController : Controller
{

    [OutputCache(3600, VaryByParam="id")]
    public ActionResult Index(Guid id)
    {
        var post = PostRepository.GetById(id);
        return View(post);
    }
}
```

When a frontend user requests `posts/{id}` the page is cached and works very well. But...

The posts are created on another site (a backend in a different assembly), and sometimes, the backend user wants to fix a typo or change the post in any way. She can do this task with no problem (since the backend is not affected by the cache). But, obviously, the frontend user must waits for the cache to invalidate to read the most recent version. Is there a way to trigger a frontend cache refresh when the user updates the post in the backend?